# Counting integer tuples with specific property

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

Given two numbers M_max,M_min count all the r-tuples of prime numbers (M_1,...,M_r) such that:

1. M_min < M_i < M_max
2. every M_i-1 is divisible by at least one square of an odd prime
3. lcm(M_1-1,...,M_r-1)=(M_1-1)*(M_2-1)...(M_r-1)/2^(r-1)

**Rephrased Question**: How many r-tuples among the k numbers M_1,M_2,...,M_k are coprime?

Comment: Can you clarify condition two a little more. Does it means only **one**  square of an odd prime or **at least one** square of an odd prime?

Comment: @Gray_Rhino at least one square, it is not odd-squarefree in particular

Comment: I assume that in condition 3 it should be `2^r+1` instead of `2^r-1`?

Comment: @btilly No it is stated that way

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code.  In fairly unoptimized Python.

```
# Stupid simple Euclidean primes filter.
def primes ():
    found_primes = []
    factor_filter = [False, False]
    block_size = 2

    candidate = 2
    while True:
        factor_filter.extend([False for _ in factor_filter])
        for p in found_primes:
            if 2*block_size <= p*p:
                break
            i = ((block_size + p - 1) // p) * p
            while i < 2 * block_size:
                factor_filter[i] = 1
                i = i + p

        block_size += block_size

        while (candidate < block_size):
            if 0 == factor_filter[candidate]:
                yield candidate
                found_primes.append(candidate)
            candidate = candidate + 1

def factor_range (m, n):
    factored = []
    remainder = []
    for i in range(n - m + 1):
        factored.append({})
        remainder.append(i+m)

    for p in primes():
        if n < p*p:
            break
        else:
            count = 1
            q = p
            while q <= n:
                # Find the first thing divisible by q
                i = ((m + q - 1) // q) * q
                while i <= n:
                    factored[i-m][p] = count
                    remainder[i-m] = remainder[i-m] // p
                    i += q
                q = p*q
                count += 1

    for i in range(len(remainder)):
        if 1 < remainder[i]:
            factored[i][remainder[i]] = 1

    return factored

def int_tuples (m, n, j):
    factored = factor_range(m, n)

    available = []
    for i in range(len(factored)):
        if 0 < i and i + m in factored[i]:
            for p, count in factored[i-1].items():
                if 2 < p and 1 < count:
                    available.append(i+m)
                    break

    prime_divides = {}
    for i in available:
        if m < i:
            for p, count in factored[i-1-m].items():
                if 1 < count or p != 2:
                    if p not in prime_divides:
                        prime_divides[p] = set([i])
                    else:
                        prime_divides[p].add(i)

    options_stack = [(-1, available, False)]
    chosen = []
    while 0 < len(options_stack):
        #print(("...", chosen, options_stack))
        i, options, is_pop = options_stack.pop()
        i = i+1
        if len(chosen) == j:
            yield tuple(chosen)
            if is_pop:
                chosen.pop()
        elif len(chosen) + len(options) - i < j:
            # Cannot generate an answer.
            if is_pop:
                chosen.pop()
        elif len(options) <= i:
            # i reached the end.
            if is_pop:
                chosen.pop()
        else:
            options_stack.append((i, options, is_pop))
            chosen.append(options[i])
            options = options[i:]
            for p, count in factored[options[0]-1].items():
                if p == 2 and 1 == count:
                    continue
                if p in prime_divides:
                    options = [option for option in options if option not in prime_divides[p]]
            options_stack.append((-1, options, True))
```

The idea is to find tuples such that the `(M-1)/2` reduced series are pairwise relatively prime to each other.  Which I'm doing by what amounts to a recursive search.  However I kept explicit stacks so that I could make a generator by simply doing a `yield`.

My first try involved keeping bitvectors for efficiency.  But a heavier weight data structure followed by determining "don't search farther" conclusions earlier works out better.

---

I decided to try recursive after all, and I'm glad I did.  The use of caching is yet another step towards having a heavyweight data structure to avoid repeated calculations.

```
# Stupid simple Euclidean primes filter.
def primes ():
    found_primes = []
    factor_filter = [False, False]
    block_size = 2

    candidate = 2
    while True:
        # We get here when we need to double the length of our sieve.
        # First add new elements.
        factor_filter.extend([False for _ in factor_filter])
        # Cross off the ones that divisible by known primes.
        for p in found_primes:
            if 2*block_size <= p*p:
                break
            i = ((block_size + p - 1) // p) * p
            while i < 2 * block_size:
                factor_filter[i] = True
                i = i + p

        # Record that we did so.
        block_size += block_size

        # Now that we have sieved, start returning primes.
        while (candidate < block_size):
            if 0 == factor_filter[candidate]:
                yield candidate
                found_primes.append(candidate)
            candidate = candidate + 1

# Takes a range of numbers, factors all of them at once.
def factor_range (m, n):
    # This will hold the factorization.
    factored = []
    # This will hold the remainder we have not factorized.
    remainder = []
    # We start with no factors and the number as remainder.
    for i in range(n - m + 1):
        factored.append({})
        remainder.append(i+m)

    # We run through the primes up to sqrt(n)    
    for p in primes():
        if n < p*p:
            break
        else:
            # For each power of p, we add it to the factorization and divide it form the remainder.
            count = 1
            q = p
            while q <= n:
                # Find the first thing divisible by q
                i = ((m + q - 1) // q) * q
                while i <= n:
                    factored[i-m][p] = count
                    remainder[i-m] = remainder[i-m] // p
                    i += q
                q = p*q
                count += 1

    # Any left-over remainders must be primes.    
    for i in range(len(remainder)):
        if 1 < remainder[i]:
            factored[i][remainder[i]] = 1

    return factored

# This function does all of the work.
def _int_tuples (m, n, j):
    # BUG FIX HERE:
    # If our minimum is odd, extend the boundary down one.
    # This does not introduce new solutions, but does mean we
    # factorize all of the numbers that we need.
    if 1 == m // 2:
        m = m-1

    # Factorize all numbers.
    factored = factor_range(m, n)

    # available will be all of our candidate primes.
    available = []
    for i in range(len(factored)):
        if 0 < i and i + m in factored[i]:
            for p, count in factored[i-1].items():
                if 2 < p and 1 < count:
                    available.append(i+m)
                    break

    # Construct a data structure to answer, "which other candidate primes
    # have p-1 share a non-trivial factor with this one"
    prime_divides = {}
    for i in available:
        if m < i:
            for p, count in factored[i-1-m].items():
                if 1 < count or p != 2:
                    if p not in prime_divides:
                        prime_divides[p] = set([i])
                    else:
                        prime_divides[p].add(i)

    # PERFORMANCE HACK: We will recurse over lists of remaining candidates.
    # Putting candidates that eliminate lots of other candidates first
    # makes those lists smaller and that recursion more efficient.  We
    # also improve the odds that we will be looking at a list we have
    # already seen and already have an answer for.  And, finally, the
    # candidates at the end of our list will largely not filter each
    # other out.  So we are spending time on things that are more likely to
    # give us more solutions.
    count_related = {}
    for i in available:
        total = 0
        for p, count in factored[i-1-m].items():
            if 1 < count or p != 2:
                total += len(prime_divides[p]) - 1
        count_related[i] = total
    available = sorted(available, key = lambda i: -count_related[i])

    # To spend less time filtering, forget about the primes that only
    # divide one thing.
    for p in list(prime_divides.keys()):
        if 1 == len(prime_divides[p]):
            i = list(prime_divides[p])[0] # Get the element
            prime_divides.pop(p)
            factored[i-m-1].pop(p)

    # We will keep a cache of already computed results.
    # That way we do not have to recalculate them.  This trick
    # is called "memoizing".
    cache = {}

    # Recursive search here.  options are remaining candidate primes
    # and needed are how many more of them we need.
    # It returns (count_solutions, data_structure_encoding_solutions)
    def search (options, needed):
        # This is the key we will cache results under.
        key = (tuple(options), needed)
        # Return trivial base cases.
        if 0 == needed:
            return [1, None]
        elif len(options) < needed:
            return [0, None]
        elif key not in cache:
            # It is not trivial, and we have never calculated it.
            # Actually do work.
            answer = []
            total = 0
            # For each first candidate we can choose.
            for i in range(len(options) - needed + 1):
                # Remaining candidates are farther along.
                next_options = options[i+1:]
                # Filter out ones whose p-1 shares a factor with this one.
                for p, count in factored[options[i] - m-1].items():
                    if p == 2 and 1 == count:
                        # All are even, don't filter on p=2 unless divisible by 4.
                        continue
                    # Use list comprehension to do the filtering.
                    next_options = [option for option in next_options if option not in prime_divides[p]]
                # Now the recursive call.
                count, result = search(next_options, needed - 1)
                # Did we find any?
                if 0 < count:
                    total += count
                    answer.append([options[i], result])
            # cache it
            cache[key] = [total, answer]
        # and return the cached answer
        return cache[key]

    # And actually do the recursive search.    
    return search(available, j)

# The count is the first thing returned.
def count_int_tuples (m, n, j):
    return _int_tuples(m, n, j)[0]

# This will yield all of the tuples
def int_tuples (m, n, j):
    # the encoded data structure is the second thing returned.
    # It has the structure:
    # [
    #    [p1, recursive_encoding of the rest],
    #    [p2, recursive_encoding of the rest],
    #    ...
    # ]
    #
    data = _int_tuples(m, n, j)[1]
    # chosen is our chosen primes.  Since processing always pops first,
    # before sticking the next candidate in, it needs to start with
    # something, anything.  That will be thrown away.
    chosen = [None]
    # Think of stack as a recursive call stack.  Each call has a
    # (position, data).
    # We start before the beginning of all of our data.
    stack = [(-1, data)]
    # While there is work to do...
    while 0 < len(stack):
        # get the next call
        i, data = stack.pop()
        # clear the previous choice
        chosen.pop()
        # advance
        i = i+1

        # If we have another (candidate, more_data) pair to process
        if i < len(data):
            # Choose our candidate
            chosen.append(data[i][0])
            # Add walking through current data to the call stack.
            stack.append([i, data])
            # Did we get a full solution?
            if j == len(chosen):
                # Return it here, then continue.
                # If that is confusing, look up Python iterators.
                yield chosen
            else:
                # Add a recursive call to this data structure.
                # Because stacks are Last In First Out (LIFO), this
                # will be processed before undoing our choice.
                stack.append([-1, data[i][1]])
                chosen.append(None)
```

If I run `print(count_int_tuples(2, 40000, 3))` on my laptop, it takes just over a second to decide that there are 2,198,808 tuples of length 3 meeting your condition.

Comment: Actual running code is much appreciated! Just a couple of questions though: what is the complexity for small r? Where do I give the input Mi values?

Comment: Essentially you group the numbers by their prime factors and append if they are in different classes? Excuse my constant flow of questions, I am having trouble grasping the different functions

Comment: `factored` is an array of factorizations.  `available` is the list of all numbers in the range meeting your conditions.  `prime_divides` is, for all primes that divide 2+ in `available`, a list of all of the numbers that the prime divides.  `chosen` is the set of current choices on the way to the next solution.  And each frame of `options_stack` can be thought of as a recursive call frame.

Comment: @RedPilled I also added a recursive solution.

Comment: Great! Really appreciated! Seems like way more than I asked for. I will try to figure the exact complexity tomorrow and get back to the site

Comment: Your laptop must be a beast btw (or mine trash), it took close to 40" on mine...

Comment: @RedPilled I was running it under PyPy.  That makes a huge difference.

Comment: It works great but could you briefly describe in high level language how it works? So far I get that you find the list of Mi numbers, and store them in an array of primes based on their factorization. You then count the options based on the primes not dividing the number. I fail to see what is the recusrion formula however. Is it recursion on r based on the chosen primes from the r-1 run?

Comment: @RedPilled Recursion is based on the primes not filtered out by already chosen ones, and how many more we need to pick.  So we go through available primes, try choosing each in turn.  When we choose it, we filter the rest of the list and call again.

Comment: @RedPilled I made it several times as fast and added a lot of comments.

Comment: Amazing! Now it's lightning fast and perfectly clear!